# SVG Icons from extrnal file not rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, symbols

My svg icons are rendering fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In the case of chrome, the use tag connects with the corresponding symbol tag in my external file. Not so with Firefox. Website is rendered via https.

Inspector Console in Chrome:

```
<use href="/static/media/icons.6a99d84f.svg#sun" class="srkBlack" transform="translate(151.00535764116418 69.12489159171793)scale(.4)">
  #shadow-root (closed)
  <svg id="sun" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3.4;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 16.136067,15.83614 h 0.09665 v 0.09665 h -0.09665 z m -9.6934884,0.263275 a 9.6572458,9.6572463 0 1 0 19.3144874,0 9.6572458,9.6572463 0 1 0 -19.3144874,0 m 8.6915274,0 a 0.96572559,0.96572565 0 1 0 1.931451,0 0.96572559,0.96572565 0 1 0 -1.931451,0"></path>
</svg>
</use>
```

Inspector Console in Firefox:

```
<use href="/static/media/icons.6a99d84f.svg#sun" class="srkBlack" transform="translate(62.2828608746849 157.56870700757347)scale(.4)">
  #shadow-root (closed)
</use>
```

css:

```
.srkBlack {
  fill:black; 
  stroke:black;
}
```

Icons.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="sun" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3.4;stroke-opacity:1"
  d="m 16.136067,15.83614 h 0.09665 v 0.09665 h -0.09665 z m -9.6934884,0.263275 a 9.6572458,9.6572463 0 1 0 19.3144874,0 9.6572458,9.6572463 0 1 0 -19.3144874,0 m 8.6915274,0 a 0.96572559,0.96572565 0 1 0 1.931451,0 0.96572559,0.96572565 0 1 0 -1.931451,0" />
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by sending the Icons.svg file thru http://svg.enshrined.co.uk/.

There were a few missing tags that chrome forgave, but Firefox did not.

Comment: What missing tags? This would be a better answer if you compared the working file to the non-working file.

Answer (score 0):

There were missing closing symbol tags. I was actually able to find them by examining the icons.svg file, but it took a while. Just to see if I could have used an online validator to speed up the process, I took the other approach. Both resulting files were identical.